# Navbar: when I fixed the navbar to the top, my components are also fixed to the top

Tags: css, angular, navbar, fixed

I work on a personnal project with Angular. I want to have a top fixed navbar to write "fixed-top" in `<nav>`. The navbar is fixed but the probleme is that my components are also fixed to the top which is a big issue that I don't know how to resolve.
Has you can see in my screen, my component movie list is also fixed to the top so the top of the component is hide by the navbar. It is that probleme with all components/pages.

[[This is a screen of my app.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7kda.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7kda.png)

This is my navbar template

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="../../assets/logo1.png" alt="">
        </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Search
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="search/movie">Movie</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="search/tv-show">Tv Show</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="movies">Movies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
          <a class="nav-link"routerLink="tv-shows">Tv Shows</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is the css

```css
nav {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px -1px rgba(173,161,173,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px -1px rgba(173,161,173,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px -1px rgba(173,161,173,1);
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
}
```

This is my app component calling the navbar

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If you have some idea please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
<nav class=". . . fixed-top . . .">
```

You have specified the `fixed-top` class. That implies that navbar will overlap beneath contents.

You could try removing that class. Or, if you want that specific class, try adding a padding: `body { padding-top: 80px; }` (80px or what you find it more confortable for web content shown).